# Need help understanding proof on the tails of the binomial distribution

Tags: probability, algorithms

[image]

I am not sure how the last line was derived from the previous. Also, a general explanation / reasoning of the proof would help a lot! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not post unsearchable pictures.  Instead, typeset your question in *MathJax*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is the total number of successes.  So $P(X=k)$ is the probability of getting $k$ successes in all.

The $A_S$'s are a way of labeling everything that can happen.  The label $S$ stands for the set of trials that were successes.  Every event is some $A_S$. If you want the probability of at least $k$ successes, then you want to know if the event "these $k$ trials were successes" ever happened, in any arrangement.  You want to know if any of the $A_S$'s that have that property are true.  That's what they are saying with that first line.

The sum is over subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ of size $k$.  There are ${n \choose k}$ such subsets, and each of them has probability $p^k$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also please explain the first line of the proof?

Comment: They are talking about a subset $A_S$ being true when every element in it is a success.  The probability of $k$ successes is $p^k$.  So if the size of $S = k$, then the probability of $A_S$ is $p^k$.

Comment: That makes sense, but I am not understanding how they are relating that to Pr{X ≥ k}.

Comment: I added detail, hopefully that answers your confusion.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you! It makes sense that only knowing that k trials were successes is the equivalent of knowing at least k trials were successes.